# Most recent version of the Breezejs metadata schema

Tags: breeze

We are creating metadata for breeze by hand to support DTO objects.  I found the metadata schema reference on the breeze website, but in the example, it gives the metadata version as version 1.0.2.

That raises the question: how do I get the most recent version of the metadata schema?  Has the schema changed since version 1.0.2.

Should I be using a different means of creating my metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the latest metadata schema [here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/tree/master/docs/metadata). There has been changes to the schema since 1.0.2 but the domain-specific language to [create breeze client metadata by hand](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) hasn't changed since it was first introduced in version 1.4.4. We're currently on version [1.4.12](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download#release%20notes).

Hope this helps.